# Print each item in a JSON Object as separate row in excel file using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to read the json from an URL, and paste the json object items as a separate row in an excel sheet.

But till now, I'm able to fetch the entire json object into the excel in single column A1.

I tried to iterate through the json objects and print in separate rows.

But getting 424 Error : Object Qualifier

Need your help on the same.

Sample Data : {"data":{"id":3,"name":"true red","year":2002,"color":"#BF1932","pantone_value":"19-1664"},"support":{"url":"https://reqres.in/#support-heading","text":"To keep ReqRes free, contributions towards server costs are appreciated!"}}

```
Private Sub HTML_VBA_Extract_Data_From_Website_To_Excel()
Dim oXMLHTTP As Object
Dim sPageHTML  As String
Dim sURL As String

'Change the URL before executing the code. URL to Extract data from.
sURL = "https://reqres.in/api/products/3"

'Extract data from website to Excel using VBA
Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
oXMLHTTP.Open "GET", sURL, False
oXMLHTTP.send
sPageHTML = oXMLHTTP.responseText

Dim jsonObject As Object
Set jsonObject = JsonConverter.ParseJson(sPageHTML)

Dim i As Integer
Dim Item As Variant
i = 2
For Each Item In jsonObject.Keys
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value = Item
    i = i + 1
    Next

MsgBox "XMLHTML Fetch Completed"

End Sub
```

[image: Data_Fetched]

Comment: Thank you for showing your code. But it would be helpful if you indicate which line returns the error.  Also, your screenshot of data is virtually useless for doing proper troubleshooting. Having to manually enter the data is discouraging to those who might assist you. To make the data useful edit your question to post it as text, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables),

Comment: Sure Ron , will do it . The error doesn’t prompt to any line . Initially it was showing i = i + 1 line but after declaring the variable , it’s throwing like a common error and doesn’t point any line .

Comment: If it is a VBA error, the code should have stopped on the line that caused the error.  What line did the code stop on?  Also, I do not see your data in text form.

Comment: Sorry for the delay Ron, I have added the url in the code itself and have shared the sample data. I'm not quite sure of why 424 error occurs, I thought I had not defined variables but updated everything. Trying this for first time, so I'm not sure how to overcome this.

Answer (score 0):

This outputs:

```txt
data
support
--------
id             3 
name          true red
year           2002 
color         #BF1932
pantone_value 19-1664
```

to the Immediate window, as expected.

```vb
Private Sub JsonTester()
    
    Dim oXMLHTTP As Object
    Dim sURL As String
    Dim jsonObject As Object
    Dim Item As Variant, data As Object
    
    sURL = "https://reqres.in/api/products/3"
    
    Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    oXMLHTTP.Open "GET", sURL, False
    oXMLHTTP.send
    
    Set jsonObject = JsonConverter.ParseJson(oXMLHTTP.responseText)
    
    For Each Item In jsonObject.keys
        Debug.Print Item
    Next
    
    Debug.Print "--------"
    
    Set data = jsonObject("data")
    For Each Item In data.keys
        Debug.Print Item, data(Item)
    Next
End Sub
```